# Prove every real number has a decimal expansion using archimedean property.

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Our professor gave this question and I don't exactly get his point because decimal expansion is just a way of representation. I tried some stuff but I actually can't get anywhere.

Comment: What's your definition of a real number?

Comment: Assuming that $x$ is positive. Can you prove that to each natural number $n$ there is a largest integer $a_n$ less than or equal to $10^nx$. Then show that $a_{n+1}=10a_n+d_{n+1}$, where $0\le d_{n+1}<10$. The Archimedean property comes to the fore when proving that if $x$ is positive, then not all $d_n$ can be zero.